# Make a camera app available for lock screen quick launch?

Tags: android, camera

How can I make my camera app available for "quick launch" on the Android lock screen?

The documentation for camera intents seems to all be focused on how to implement in a camera app which will take a single photo and return it to the calling application.  The lock screen quick launch seems like a totally different use case, and the "return an image" workflow obviously would not apply.  (For now, I specifically don't want to implement the "return one photo" functionality.)

Thanks for any help.  Either this seems poorly documented, or I can't figure out the proper terms to search for the proper documentation.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "quick launch". Android 4.2 supports lockscreen app widgets, which you could use to launch a camera activity I suppose.

Comment: Since Android 4.0, the slide to unlock screen has featured the ability to directly launch a camera app.  If you have more than one installed, it will ask which to use.  The question is how to get my app into that list.  http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1752241

Comment: If you find a third-party app that shows up in the list, download and install AppXplore on your device, then look at the third-party app's manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you CommonsWare.  Your comment eventually led me to...

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```