# Launch Google Camera or Default Camera over lock screen

Tags: android, camera, screen-lock

I would like to learn more about how the camera can launch over the secure lock-screen (PIN).

My goal is to have a user select either their default camera app or another camera app (like Google Camera).  I would then like to invoke or launch the camera without the user being required to enter their pin code, etc.

I have read that this is possible starting with Android 4.2.
Here is the post:
[Launch camera activity over lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966039/launch-camera-activity-over-lock-screen)

Currently in my test build the camera app launches, but the user my first unlock the device.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145410/make-a-camera-app-available-for-lock-screen-quick-launch ?

Comment: The answer in the post you linked to is correct. The Google Camera app, if installed, should start on top of a secured lock-screen.

However, if you have multiple apps that respond to this intent, the system will first bring up a disambig dialog, which required the user to unlock first.